# Clear: both overrides margin: 0 auto?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a positioning problem I need to deal with. In the container div I have two divs, which both should be horizontally centered under each other. However, I'm having problems with the positioning of the second div.

If I add clear:both div 2 gets on a new line, which is desired. However, if using clear:both margin: 0 auto; doesn't work. What could I use instead to make the div centered?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6 offset3 text-center header">
        <h1>Title...</h1>
        <p>Text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span3 offset4">
        <form>
          ...
        </form>                 
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.register .span3 {
    width: 270px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

**Output:**

```
- Without clear:both
 ____________________________________
|                                    |
|              ______       ______   |
|             |      |     |      |  |
|             | div 1|     | div 2|  |
|             |______|     |______|  |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |


- WITH clear:both
 ____________________________________
|                                    |
|              ______                |
|             |      |               |
|             | div 1|               |
|             |______|               |
|  ______                            |
| |      |                           |
| | div 2|                           |
| |______|                           |
|                                    |
|                                    |

- Desired output
 ____________________________________
|                                    |
|              ______                |
|             |      |               |
|             | div 1|               |
|             |______|               |
|              ______                |
|             |      |               |
|             | div 2|               |
|             |______|               |
|                                    |
|                                    |
```

Comment: Are you using a CSS framework like Bootstrap?

Comment: It looks okay to me. Maybe there is some other bootstrap css that's being applied.

Comment: @MarcAudet: Yes, I use Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, Bootstrap's grid system uses floats to position elements on the page.

Alas, if something is `float: left;` then `margin: 0 auto;` will not put it in the centre of the page. It will float to the left. The reason your `div`s appear offset from the left is because they have `offset-3`/`offset-4` classes applied.

To put the `div` elements in the middle of the page, I suspect you'll need to step outside of Bootstrap's grid framework and do your own thing.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need *clear* when you are not floating? *clear* only applies to floating situations.

If you remove the *clear:both* and insert only the *margin:0 auto* , both divs will be centered on the page, one below the other as you desire.

Comment: The OP is using Bootstrap, which uses floats to create the layout.